# Get a Document from a Path in ASP.NET MVC Outside of LocalHost

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 site and a bit of a problem.

On my Telerik Menu that acts like a Sidebar across all of my pages, I have a link that finds a Microsoft Word document (.docx) within my file system. I accomplished this by adding a Documents folder that has my document and then specifying a path for the link to follow. This works from any page on my localhost and does not take the user away from their current page. They just click and the document pushes to the current page the use is on.

```
                @(Html.Telerik().Menu().Name("genMenu")
                    .Orientation(MenuOrientation.Vertical)
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "items" })
                    .Items(appMenu =>
                    {
                         appMenu.Add().Text("User Guide").Url("/Documents/My%20User%20Guide.docx");
                    }))
```

On another page, I have an  html element that does a similar thing, except it retrieves an Excel sheet (.xlsx). This also works perfectly on my local host.

```
<a href="/Documents/Upload%20Template.xlsx">
            .xlsx</a>
```

However, when I get put this code out on my Dev site, I receive this error when I click either link:

```
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.
```

My site is not down, and the rest of the site is fully functional, but trying to get the documents like I would on my local host causes an error. Furthermore, it looks like my Dev site is actually taking the user directly to the links that they click. This should not happen. I know this because when I click the Telerik Menu link, it takes me to this link:

```
http://DevSite/Documents/My%20User%20Guide.docx
```

Does anyone know why this behavior is occurring on my Dev site, but not on my localhost?

I would be willing to do this completely differently, but my main goal remains the same:
Have a link that a user can click that downloads a document from within the ASP.NET MVC site file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Url.Content().  This method knows the context of your website relative to IIS and the directory path.  Maps a virtual path to an absolute path.  I had a similar issue between my localhost environment and our Dev server:

```
 <a href="@Url.Content("~/Documents/Upload%20Template.xlsx")">.xlsx</a>
```

See this article: [URL.Content()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx)

Comment: This saved me a bunch of trouble! Thanks a bunch! For anyone needing clarification on how to handle the Telerik Menu, it's this code:
appMenu.Add().Text("User Guide").Url("~/Documents/My%20User%20Guide.docx");

Turns out the .Url() method works a lot like @Url.Content.